# RMS calculator | scope and variables

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

Im trying to create a root mean square calculator for a sinusoidal function.

I'm using scipy and numpy

- It should ask for input from the user for amplitude, phase angle, angular frequency, start time, and end time.
- it should ask the user if an end time was provided and if an end time isn't provided it should automatically take the angular frequency, calculate and set the end time as the point where 10 periods have completed
- it should take the variables provided and then create a new variable called integrand
- we then take the integral of the integrand using scipy.
- I then plot this information

I'm running into some issues though. I'm new to coding and python in general, and I keep getting all kind of errors due to data types, and I believe scope. I've tried refactoring to make a lot of these calculations into individual functions, but still seem to run into issues.

So my question is, how could I refactor this code so that I'm able to pass variables from function to function without running into constant scope issues and data type errors?

I'm trying to avoid global variables since I hear that is bad practice. but I'm not sure what else to do to make my variables persist from one function to another.

```
def get_time_vars():
    user_input2 = input("Is frequency in hertz? y/n")
    if user_input2 == "y":
        frequency = (float(input("Enter frequency: ")) * 2*math.pi)
        user_input1 = input("Were you given end time? y/n?: ")
        if user_input1 == "y":
            end_time = (float(input("Enter end time: ")))
            return end_time, frequency
        elif user_input1 == "n":
            end_time = (float((1/frequency)*10))
            return end_time, frequency
        t = float(end_time - start_time)
        return t
    elif user_input2 == "n":
        frequency = (float(input("Enter frequency: ")) / 2*math.pi)
        user_input1 = input("Were you given end time? y/n?: ")
        if user_input1 == "y":
            end_time = (float(input("Enter end time: ")))
            return end_time, frequency
        elif user_input1 == "n":
            end_time = (float((1/frequency))*10 )   
            return end_time, frequency   
        t = float(end_time - start_time)
        return t

def get_ang_freq(frequency):
    angular_frequency = float(frequency*1000)
    return angular_frequency

def integrand(t, amplitude, frequency, phase_angle):
    angular_frequency = float(frequency*1000)
    instantaneous_value = float(amplitude * np.cos(angular_frequency * t + math.radians(phase_angle)))
    return float(instantaneous_value**2)

def calculate_rms(amplitude, frequency, phase_angle, end_time, start_time=0):
    result = quad(integrand, start_time,end_time, args=(amplitude, frequency, phase_angle))
    print(result)
    #rms = math.sqrt(result)
    #return rms

def plot_signal(amplitude, angular_frequency, phase_angle, end_time, start_time=0):
    time_values = np.linspace(start_time, end_time, num=1000)
    signal_values = amplitude * np.cos(angular_frequency * time_values + math.radians(phase_angle))

    plt.plot(time_values, signal_values, label='Sinusoidal Signal')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
    plt.title('Sinusoidal Signal')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

def main():
    #Determine end time and frequency
    # Input values
    phase_angle = float(input("Enter phase angle (in degrees): "))

    # Convert phase angle to radians
    phase_angle_rad = math.radians(phase_angle)

    amplitude = float(input("what is the amplitude?: "))

    # Calculate RMS value
    rms_value = calculate_rms(amplitude, frequency, phase_angle_rad, end_time, start_time)

    print("\nInput Values:")
    print(f"Amplitude: {amplitude}")
    print(f"Start Time: {start_time}")
    print(f"End Time: {end_time}")
    print(f"Frequency: {frequency} mHz")
    print(f"Phase Angle: {phase_angle} degrees")

    print("\nResults:")
    print(f"RMS Value: {rms_value}")

    # Plot the signal
    plot_signal(amplitude, frequency, phase_angle_rad, end_time, start_time=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You're calling `calculate_rms()` with 5 arguments, but you only assigned 2 of them.  Where are `frequency`, `end_time`, and `start_time` supposed to come from?

Comment: Now I see, you assign those variables in `get_time_vars()`. But you never call that function, and it doesn't return them.

Comment: You can return multiple values from a function, e.g. `return frequency, start_time, end_time`. And the caller can do `frequency, start_time, end_time = get_time_vars()`